# What's a good text editor with Mercurial support?

Tags: windows, editing, mercurial

I'm looking for a decent Windows editor with solid [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) support. I've had some trouble with Notepad++ (the Windows Explorer plugin was constantly crashing). What are some alternatives?

I'm not averse to shelling out a reasonable sum for a worthwhile product.

Comment: Please elaborate about "mercurial support". Do you mean this in the context of merging changes from different branches and resolving conflicts?

Comment: ideally, switching branches, merging and pushing or pulling to an external repo. the ability to switch branches in the editor would be fantastic, although i appreciate that merging may be out of the scope of a editor.

Comment: Try `emacs` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) is a commercial product which has:

> Configurable [tool support](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/user_and_project_tools.html) (run
>   compiler, run a batch file, integrate
>   with version control, etc.) provides
>   smart and dynamic command-line
>   interaction with active file(s)

It costs $59.95

Answer (score 2):

Have you given a try at Vim Editor?
one good advantage with this editor, we can get many plugins suiting our needs (like mercurial support) and can configure extensively.

MinSCM : An abstract front-end for Mercurial/Git/Bazaar 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2637

Answer (score 2):

I did not try but [this page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools) says that **Emacs** has mercurial support. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/index.html) is the link to Emacs for Windows and Linux.

Check out the following link as well:
**[How to use Emacs to work with Mercurial](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsMercurial.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Windows today because our Mercurial support depends on [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/), but we have made the Hg package for Atom that we use and develop at Facebook publicly available as part of Nuclide: https://atom.io/packages/nuclide.

Previously, we offered individual features of Nuclide as their own package, such as `nuclide-hg-repository`. However, due to performance issues with [installing a collection of Atom packages](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8217), we decided to release Nuclide only as a single, monolithic package. This has solved a number of reported installation issues.

Comment: Your link to the package is obsolete. Can you provide the new one?

Comment: @abyss.7 Thanks. Fixed the post and added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)?

I just did some research and found that from the [official Mercurial site](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools) they have listed a mercurial [plugin](http://sublime-text-community-packages.googlecode.com/svn/pages/Mercurial.html) for Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

- [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) + [SublimeHG](http://bitbucket.org/guillermooo/sublimehg) (not used)
- [EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/) + (pre-installed) [Mercurial|TortoiseHG as User Tools](http://rianjs.net/2011/09/how-to-use-mercurial-with-editplus) (in use)